# Как создать декоратор метода класса, который возвращает любой метод для всех экземпляров этого класса?

Tags: python, декоратор

В моей реализации это выглядит так:

```
class qwe ():
    spis = []
    def __init__ (self, name, x, y):
        self.name = name
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        qwe.spis.append (self)
    def forall (func):
        def wrapper (*args, **kwargs):
            for i in qwe.spis:
                return func(i)
        return wrapper
    @forall
    def pr(self):
        print (self.name)
        print (self.x)
        print (self.y)

p_1 = qwe('san', 10, 20)
p_2 = qwe('serg', 30, 40)
p_3 = qwe('vova', 20, 60)
qwe.pr()
```

Но в данном случае метод "pr()" возвращает только значение 0-го экземпляра

Answer (score 2, accepted):

после `return` функция завершает свой работу, поэтому у вас вызывается первый раз и функцию завершается.

Если убрать `return` то все заработает

```
class qwe ():
    spis = []
    def __init__ (self, name, x, y):
        self.name = name
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        qwe.spis.append (self)
    def forall (func):
        def wrapper (*args, **kwargs):
            for i in qwe.spis:
                func(i)
        return wrapper
    @forall
    def pr(self):
        print (self.name)
        print (self.x)
        print (self.y)

p_1 = qwe('san', 10, 20)
p_2 = qwe('serg', 30, 40)
p_3 = qwe('vova', 20, 60)
qwe.pr()
```

А если результат важен то так

```
class qwe ():
    spis = []
    def __init__ (self, name, x, y):
        self.name = name
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        qwe.spis.append (self)
    def forall (func):
        def wrapper (*args, **kwargs):
            arr = [] 
            for i in qwe.spis:
                arr.append(func(i))
            return arr
        return wrapper
    @forall
    def pr(self):
        print (self.name)
        print (self.x)
        print (self.y)

p_1 = qwe('san', 10, 20)
p_2 = qwe('serg', 30, 40)
p_3 = qwe('vova', 20, 60)
qwe.pr()
```

Answer (score 2):

В Питоне есть функция `map`, которая применяет первый аргумент (функцию) ко всем элементам списка. Обратите внимание как вызывается функция: `f(v, *args, **kwargs)`. В Питоне такой вызов соответствует более привычному `v.f(*args, **kwargs)`:

```
class qwe ():
    _lst = []

    def __init__ (self, name, x, y):
        self.name = name
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        qwe._lst.append(self)

    def forall(f):
        return lambda *args, **kwargs: map(lambda v: f(v, *args, **kwargs), qwe._lst)

    @forall
    def apply(self, f):
        return f(self)

    @forall
    def in_radius(self, radius):
        return self.x ** 2 + self.y ** 2 <= radius ** 2

lst = [qwe('san', 10, 20), qwe('serg', 30, 40), qwe('vova', 20, 60)]

print(*qwe.apply(lambda v: f'{v.name}: ({v.x}, {v.y})'), sep='\n')
print(*qwe.in_radius(55))
```

> ```
> san: (10, 20)
> serg: (30, 40)
> vova: (20, 60)
> True True False
> ```